# How to implement a scroll page arrow button with variable thickness?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering how I could change the thickness of the arrow on my website which is used as a scroll button. I would like something similar to this websites arrow in terms of thickness. [example of arrow](http://christopherc.ca)
[image: page screenshot with scroll arrow]

[Here is my codepen](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/EZLOdP)

```
.next {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-40px;
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Kind Regards,

Liam.

Comment: Use a different font? It's a "<" character using the "Roboto" font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you linked to an arrow is implemented differently than in your pen. Here's how it's done:

```css
#arrow {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-15px) translateX(5px);
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="arrow"></div>
```

Basically, you create a square, turn it 45 degrees and add a border on right and bottom sides. Now you can just change border thickness in the `border` property to change the arrow width.

P.S. you can use [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) to inspect elements on websites. I.e. if you like how something looks on some website, you can just see how they implemented it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the amazing answer! What am I doing wrong? I have copied and pasted your code and nothing happens. [my site](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/EZLOdP) Could it be something to do with the JS?

Comment: @LiamDocherty change the border color to white and you'll see ;-)

Comment: @LiamDocherty the arrow is there, it is just black on a dark background and you can't see it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the `font-size` and perhaps `font-weight` properties since the arrow you are showing is a character

Answer (score 0):

Those next elements on your codepen are text so the property you would have to use would be `font-size: 10px;`

I would also recommend using the html down triangle character: `&#9660;`

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```html
<style>
   body{ background-color: #DFBF90;}
  #arrow {
 height: 50px;
 width: 112px;
    color: white;
 border-top: none;
 border-left: none;
 margin: 100px;
 font-size: 74pt;
 transform: rotateX(63deg) rotate(90deg);
}
  </style>
<div id="arrow">></div>
```